# I'm having an issue regarding AttributeError

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
AttributeError at /addpatient_to_db
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'wardno'
```

Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/addpatient_to_db

Django Version: 2.2.5

Exception Type: `AttributeError`

Exception Value:    `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'wardno'`

Exception Location: `C:\Users\Saurabh Patil\Desktop\SanjeevniHospital\admininterface\views.py in addpatient_to_db, line 114`

Python Executable:  `C:\Users\Saurabh Patil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe`

Python Version: 3.7.4

Python Path:

```
['C:\\Users\\Saurabh Patil\\Desktop\\SanjeevniHospital',
 'C:\\Users\\Saurabh '
 'Patil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Saurabh Patil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Saurabh Patil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Saurabh Patil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Users\\Saurabh Patil\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Saurabh '
 'Patil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Server time:    Sun, 26 Jan 2020 12:07:40 +0000

Here is my code

***views.py***

```
def addpatient_to_db(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST['name']
        age = request.POST['age']
        sex = request.POST['sex']
        address = request.POST['address']
        contno = request.POST['contno']
        wardno = request.POST['wardno']
        bedno = request.POST['bedno']
        doa = request.POST['doa']
        docass = request.POST['docass']
        pii = request.POST['pii']

        alldata = patientdetails.objects.all()

        if alldata.wardno == wardno and alldata.bedno == bedno: # <---- This is the issuing line
            return render(request, "addpatient.html")
        else:
            addp = patientdetails(name=name, age=age, sex=sex, address=address, mobno=contno,
                                  wardno=wardno, bedno=bedno, dateofallot=doa, docass=docass, illness_issue=pii)
            addp.save()
            return redirect('addpatient')
    else:
        return render(request, 'addpatient.html')
```

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class patientdetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobno = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    wardno = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    bedno = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    dateofallot = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    docass = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    illness_issue = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alldata.wardn` won't work since is a `QuerySet` that contains a list of objects. If you already know that `alldata` contains only one object, then you can use `first()` ro retrieve the object:

```
alldata = patientdetails.objects.first()
```

Otherwise, if you do have multiple objects in the `QuerySet` you can simply iterate over `alldata`:

```
alldata = patientdetails.objects.all()

for patient in alldata: 
    if patient.wardno == wardno and patient.bedno == bedno:
        return render(request, "addpatient.html")
    else:
        addp = patientdetails(name=name, age=age, sex=sex, address=address, mobno=contno,
                              wardno=wardno, bedno=bedno, dateofallot=doa, docass=docass, illness_issue=pii)
        addp.save()
        return redirect('addpatient')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning queryset from this line, So you cannot access 'wardno'.

```
alldata = patientdetails.objects.all()
```

Loop throughout the queryset to access it,

```
alldata = patientdetails.objects.all()
for data in alldata:
    print(data.wardno)
```

Optimize your code as below:

```
if patientdetails.objects.filter(wardno=wardno, bedno=bedno).exists():
    return render(request, "addpatient.html")
else:
    addp = patientdetails(name=name, age=age, sex=sex, address=address, mobno=contno, wardno=wardno, bedno=bedno, dateofallot=doa, docass=docass, illness_issue=pii)
        addp.save()
        return redirect('addpatient')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is at line

```
     alldata = patientdetails.objects.all()
```

You are using a queryset that returns multiple object and you cannot hit the database with multiple object to attribute.

So what you should do here is loop through each item in querysets and then only access attribute

```
     for eachQueryset in alldata:
         if eachQueryset.wardno == wardno and eachQueryset.bedno ==bedno:
               return render(request, "addpatient.html")
         else:
              addp = patientdetails(name=name, age=age, sex=sex, 
                       address=address,mobno=contno,wardno=wardno,bedno=bedno, 
                           dateofallot=doa, docass=docass, illness_issue=pii)
              addp.save()
              return redirect('addpatient')
```

and this should solve your issue

Comment: sorry i made a mistake initially i looped through all data and again used used alldata to query an attribute. I have made change and it will work